# How to edit a non logged in page?

Tags: plugins, customization

Having difficulty editing a 'non logged in' page on wordpress using elementor.

Every time I logon to wordpress it only shows me the logged on view but I need to edit a page that is logged out.

I know I can view it in another or private browser but im pulling my hair out trying to edit that page

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks
Jo